# Airflow: How can Python script signal a failed task when run using BashOperator

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow-scheduler, airflow

When running a Python script using `BashOperator` of Airflow 1.10.9,

```
task_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    bash_command='/path/to/env/python /path/to/task_1.py'
    dag=dag)
```

what can be done inside the Python script to signal to Airflow that this task has failed?

**task_1.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Task failed!')
    # How do we tell Airflow that the `task_1` has failed?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise a Python Exception that should send exit code of 1 to BashOperator which should fail.